TailwindCSS prefixes are being ignored sometimes
This works:
<div class="hidden xl:block"></div>

The div will be hidden on smaller screens and displayed starting from the xl breakpoint.
These, however, don't work as I believe they should:
<div class="text-blue xl:text-red"></div>
<div class="text-start xl:text-center"></div>
<div class="px-5 xl:px-20"></div>

The div will have text-blue, text-start, px-5 applied on all screen sizes, and the class after the xl prefix will be completely ignored.
By inspecting the code in the developer tools, I found that the class px-5 has the following properties:
.px-5 {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
}

Whereas for px-20, we only have the margin-left and margin-right, but the !important isn't there. So px-5 applies all the way.
According to Tailwind's documentation, if we have the classes px-5 xl:px-20, then px-5 should be applied on smaller screens, and px-20 should be applied from the xl breakpoint, but it's never happening for me.
sm:px-5 xl:px-20 will work as intended, however, the smallest screens won't have any padding at all, because under the sm breakpoint xs:px-5 xl:px-20 will not work at all.
I didn't find a solution on StackOverflow or on Google. Did I misunderstand how Tailwind works?
I tried reversing the classes, like so: xl:px-20 px-5, but of course, that didn't change anything.
I tried adding the important tag to the xl class, like so: sm:px-5 !xl:px-20, but that didn't work either.
I tried adding  important: true in tailwind.config.js, and that did add !important to the px-20 class' attributes, but px-5 still won.
I rebuilt the assets with npm, I cleared the cache and the config, I searched on Google, I asked ChatGPT, I just can't find a solution.

There is no such thing as text-blue in Tailwind, it is text-blue-X where X is value. Also, it is not possible to have !important on Inspect panel, probably you added some config, but it is not needed.

Agree with prev commenter. Don't add !important to anything, and it'll work. px-5 does not have !important in Tailwind, so that's added in your project. Remove it.

As mentioned in comment, you need to know how Tailwind works, and try not to use !important at all.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="text-blue-400 xl:text-red-400">Text is blue by default, it is red on large screens</div>
<div class="text-start xl:text-center">Text is aligned on start by default, on large screen it is centered.</div>
<div class="px-5 xl:px-20">Padding horizontally by 20px default, 160px on large screens </div>



with default config.
It is not recommended to use !important at all.

Your understanding is correct for how responsive design utils function in Tailwind. I have created a minimal code block to represent this. Take for example, this HTML:
<div class="h-56 w-56 border border-stone-500 px-5 xl:px-20">
  <div class="h-full w-full border border-stone-500" />
</div>

or if you prefer React:
const PaddingExample = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-56 w-56 border border-stone-500 px-5 xl:px-20">
      <div className="h-full w-full border border-stone-500" />
    </div>
  )
}


If you resize the window, you will see that px-5 is applied when the window is horizontally smaller than xl or 1280px. Otherwise, the padding adjusts to px-20.
As for why Tailwind's responsive design utilities aren't working in your case, it must be environmental or specific to what you're working on. Try to reduce your problem down to the bare essentials and compare it with this code.
As a side note, this is probably not an appropriate use case for the important modifier.
